# Pairwise comparisons after ANOVA with Tukey and Bonferroni methods in r

Tags: r, anova, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, tukey-hsd-test

The built-in functions TukeyHSD and LSD.test from R perform pairwise comparisons. In order to maintain the type I error, the significance level $0.05$ is divided by the number of comparisons $k$. Do these built-in functions take into account the new significance level $0.05/k$ by default? Or do we need to indicate this fact in some of the options of the functions?

Comment: Your statement is incorrect - the correction you mention, alpha/k, is in fact the Bonferroni correction (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction).  Tukey's correction is quite different - see, for example, https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/prc/section4/prc471.htm.

Comment: See https://rpubs.com/aaronsc32/post-hoc-analysis-tukey for insights into how Tukey's correction really works.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Ok, so I understand that Tukey works in a different manner. In the case of [LSD.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/agricolae/versions/1.2-8/topics/LSD.test) in R, if we put p.adj="bonferroni", do we put the option alpha=0.05, or alpha=0.05/k ?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game here to answer your question, but short answer is that you would put `alpha=0.05` and let the function do the adjustment for you.

If you were to scroll a little bit further down the [documentation for LSD.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/agricolae/versions/1.2-8/topics/LSD.test) to the "detail" section, it indicates that if you provide the argument `p-adj="none"` you'll be getting a normal t-test.